# Do clipless pedals that can have toeclips exist?

Tags: pedals, clipless

I know there are several clipless that can also be used as platform pedals.

But i'm looking for something that can also have a toeclip.

I'm dreaming with something like those:

[image]
[image]

PLUS this half toe clip:

[image]

Even more ideal would be if it wasn't permanently attached so i could carry it with the bike and just clip it there if i'm w/out my bike shoes.

Does anything like this exists? know of any try/success history about someone hacking it together?

---

Bonus question: if i find a way to attach the half toe clip on the deore XT, maybe 1,5cm more forward than my shoes stay when clipped... would that work? or am i missing any obvious reason it wouldn't?

Comment: Bonus answer: as far as I know, if you have clip you don't need and DON'T WANT an additional toeclip, since it could cause problems on emergency and even regular stops. Also, why the h*ll do you want to use both at the same time?

Comment: I may be with heltonbiker on this. Why? Surely possible, but why?

Comment: Ah. I see now. You'd like to be able to hop on without the bike shoes?

Comment: @heltonbiker i want both on the same pedal. NOT both at the same time. that's why i would install it a little more forward than my feet rest when cliped. So, case#1: special shoes clipped, straps too open (or removed) and feet not deep enough to hang on toeclip. Case#2: regular shoes, feet deep enough to hang on toeclip, strap pulled. Case#3 special shoes, does not clip, and fully insert foot for a quick go-n-stop.

Comment: @gcb : Fine, much clearer now. This is a true DIY idea, and this is good! Just for the record, I ride clipless pedals with regular shoes (no cleats, rubber sole) almost every day. It takes some time to get used, but works very well and is simplest.

Comment: Attaching toe clips to one side of a clipless pedal is not a good idea. Mac's suggestion that you add clips and straps to a one-sided (or half-and-half) clipless pedal is workable, but potentially dangerous. The toe-clips that dangle well below the pedal level are likely to drag and/or catch on something on the ground at some point thus increasing your risk of a crash. An alternative to traditional clips-and-straps is the so-called "Power Grip", which  could tuck away more easily when using the cleat. Or just swap between pedals. Quick-release pedals (marketed for folding bikes) would help.

Comment: I want these too. For a super sprint duathlon I don't want to have to change my shoes twice as this is a waste of time, so I want to jump on my racing bike with running shoes on. To do this I want a toe-clip mounted on a cleat that I can prefix to my pedals. I don't want a pedal with permanently combined toe-clip on one side and cleat on the other. I understand that I can have two pairs of pedals and swap them but I'm lazy and don't want to do this. Also, I don't want to have to swap pedals if I decide to cycle to work and don't want to wear my bike shoes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The guy who sponsors my team at the Dick Lane Velodrome converts standard Speedplay Zero pedals to have [toe clips](http://prollyisnotprobably.com/2010/08/bill_thomsen_speedplay_toe_cli.php). You might be able to contact him to have him make some for you.

[image: speedplay pedal with straps]

Comment: Thank you man! I just bought cheap bebop pedals (hint, anyone have a spare cleats for it, i'm buying!) and might try this! exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: actually a very clever design... it even have the tab on the back to rotate the pedal like a full sized mountain bike pedal... too bad i got bebops and not speedplays. will email him and see if he can work one with a way to attach to bebops.

Comment: Did you have any luck?

Comment: my email is still unanswered... But now i'm searching for a Bebop Cleat, since i'm too cheap to pay $50 on something i don't even know i will like. After i have that, i will work on the adapter as shown above.

Answer (score 13):

There are [pedals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AES1u.jpg) that have a cleat clip on one side and a traditional platform pedal on the other side. You could attach the clip to the platform side and use the cleat side when you're riding with cycling shoes.

You might have problems when you're clipped in because the toe clip might hang too low and catch the road when you're leaning into corners.

[image]

Comment: And please, DON'T mount the toeclip in the clip side unless you want to hurt yourself.

Comment: but if the toe clip is on the under side, it will hang on the floor everytime i'm 'cliped'

Comment: As an aside, I have these pedals on my commuter. They are *unbelievably* heavy. It's like they're made of gold or something. There seems to be more mass there than you would think would be possible for something so small.

Comment: note: the site i got the image with the clipless plus toecage under it, was a 'indoor cycle' store.

Comment: Several brands of pedals are sold primarily to the exercise bike market with SPD clips on one side and toe clips on the other.  Some brands are really sucky (the SPD clips are virtually unusable), but others fairly decent.

Answer (score 2):

A wide variety of pedals exist with toe clips on one side and the "clipless" clip on the other side.  Generally more of the full strap variety toe clips, though some may be able to have them swapped out for the style in your picture.

Mostly you'll see this arrangement with the SPD style pedals, though.

One problem you'll experience is that the toe clip will tend to drag on the ground in certain situations.

You also can (or at least could, at one time) purchase adapters that clip into clipless pedals and provide a toe clip mounting.  Mostly intended for when you use street shoes.  I have a pair of these, though I've never used them much.

Comment: what are those clips called? that would be an ideal solution. i could carry those on bag with the night lights.

Comment: I'll see if I can remember to dig them out and look for a brand name.  I've had them for 12-15 years, and never really used them.

Comment: Well, though I remembered where those clip-on toe clips were, but when I looked there I couldn't find them.  Will have to dig though several other piles....

Answer (score 2):

It is much better to get a pair of your favorite clipless and a pair of your favorite toe-clip pedals and then just swap them out a pedal wrench when needed. It only takes minute and you don't need to torque the pedal too hard.

Answer (score 1):

You used to be able to get Insteps for Look pedals. These were plastic toe-clips with moulded-in cleats, which used standard straps. The "stand height" was a bit higher than using the Look shoes, but they were ideal for short trips. There is a similar product on the market now, but it places your foot about half an inch higher than normal, so is rubbish. for SPDs, I can find nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Think i've found one

http://www.flickr.com/photos/steveparry/2091942712/in/photostream/
[image: vintage shimano 105 pedal]

Comment: That's just a regular toe-clip from "back in the day". It actually uses special shoes that are hard to find, something like these: http://www.dromarti.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=11&products_id=18

Comment: So it doesn't really 'clip'? so it's the same as my current setup... cross pedals with toeclips used with trail shoes to lock on the pedal... thanks for the clarification

Comment: Yes, before clipless pedals, we still wore special shoes for cycling. They had a plastic piece on the sole that helped to keep your foot in place, but it was the strap that held your foot to the pedal. This is one of those pedals that worked with those types of shoes.

Comment: @Angelo You had plastic cleats?  In my day we had to make cleats by banging granite stones together.  :)